# Virtualenvwrapper - correct set up of .bash_profile

Tags: python, linux, unix, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am running python3 on Linux Mint, and am trying to set up VirtualEnvWrapper.

I have both virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper installed:
Running `sudo pip3 install virtualenv`, returns `Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (15.1.0)`

Running `sudo pip3 install virtualenvwrapper`, returns `Requirement already satisfied: virtualenvwrapper in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (4.8.2)`

virtualenv is in /home/username/.local/bin/virtualenv
virtualenvwrapper.sh is in /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

My .bash_profile looks like:

```
source ~/.profile
export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

When I run `source ~/.bash_profile` and then `mkvirtualenv TestEnv`, I return the following error:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such 
file or directory
```

I think this is an issue with my .bash_profile and the location of the virtualenv vs virtualenvwrapper files. Is anyone able to help me correct my bash_profile to resolve this. I have tried various solutions offered on other threads, but none have helped.

Many thanks

Addition:
This is a selection of the contents of my /usr/bin directory (i.e. `ls`). I'm not sure why `python` is in red but it is neither a file nor a directory

[image]

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but try using [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv). I've found it to be a much simpler solution than virtualenv by itself.

Comment: If you don't have `/usr/bin/python` on your system many tools in Mint shouldn't work. Did you uninstall the OS Python?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper are software tools commonly used by Python programmers so the question is completely on-topic. Please revoke your close vote.

Comment: @KlausD. - I juste added a screenshot above of my `/usr/bin/`directory contents. Python2 and Python3 are there but not Python. I think I did uninstall and then reinstall the OS Python in following some suggestions elsewhere. How do I move it back to its correct location please? Thanks

Comment: Following https://askubuntu.com/questions/218919/i-accidentally-deleted-usr-bin-python-how-do-i-restore-it , I tried to run `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python`. However, it returned an error `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/python': File exists`. 

I tried `nano python` which came up with `Error writing lock file ./.python.swp: Permission denied`. 

I tried to `rm /usr/bin/python` but this returned `rm: cannot remove '/usr/bin/python': Permission denied`.

Any ideas please? I do have /usr/bin/python2.7 as a text file

Thanks!

Comment: The first command was correct (`sudo ln -s ...`) but ) before you need to do `sudo rm /usr/bin/python`. Always double-ckeck what you are deleting with `sudo`!

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using python3, I would check this file: `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv`. Be sure that, on the 1st line there you have something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Save the file and try again.

I'm pretty sure that right now you have /usr/bin/python which most probably referrs to python2 and not 3. So you're trying to run a python3 script using python2 (that's why you get a bad interpreter error).

Since `/usr/bin/python` is a symbolic link to a file that no longer exists at that location, the `/usr/bin/python` is show with red.

Delete it with sudo: `sudo rm -f /usr/bin/python`
Then re-create the symlink using the following syntax: `ln -s /path/to/source /path/to/destination` (in your case /usr/bin/python)

Then try execute `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv` and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @BogdanStoica. I have just inspected the file at /user/local/bin/virtualenv and the first line is `#!/usr/bin/python3` as you suggest it should be. Do you have any other suggestions please? Many thanks

Comment: python is in red because it is/was a symbolic link to another file. Do a `ls -lsa /usr/bin/python*`. It should show you to which file it was supposed to link

Comment: Thanks @BogdanStoica . When I run that command, I see `/usr/bin/python -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python`. How best do I relink this please? Thanks

Comment: ln -s source destination, that’s the syntax

Comment: @BogdanStoica I tried to run `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python` but got an error `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/python': File exists`. Is this not the symbolic link you meant?

Comment: You should delete /usr/bin/python first then re-create the symlink

Comment: @BogdanStoica I also tried to `rm /usr/bin/python` but that failed as it is protected `rm: cannot remove '/usr/bin/python': Permission denied`

Comment: Try to remove it with sudo: sudo rm -f /usr/bin/python

Comment: Thank you @BogdanStoica
With a tweak to my .bash_profile, I now have the mkvirtualenv wrapper functioning! Appreciate the help

Comment: I've edited my answer so it includes the instructions from the comments. Now the answer should be complete. I would really appreciate if you would accept it as answer. Thanks